# Expects 2 arguments but found only 1

Tags: racket

I am doing a practice question where it asks to define a function that is supposed to produce all elements in a list, loi, that can be divided by 3 or a natural number, mult, but not both.

Below is my code:

```
(define (keep-multiples-of-three-or loi mult)
  (cond
    [(empty? loi) empty]
    [else (cond [(empty? loi) empty]
                [(and (not (equal? 3 mult)) 
                      (or (equal? (remainder (first loi) 3) 0)
                          (equal? (remainder (first loi) mult) 0)))   
                 (first loi)]           
                [else (keep-multiples-of-three-or (rest-loi) 
                                                  mult)]))]))
```

for `(keep-multiples-of-three-or (cons 9 (cons 3 empty)) 3)` 
the error message says: `cons expects 2 arguments but found only 1`.

I don’t know what is wrong here. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors:

- There's no need to nest the `cond` expression
- The `[(empty? loi) empty]` case is repeated two times
- It's not `(rest-loi)`, it's `(rest loi)`
- In the second case, you need to `cons` the result and call the recursion again
- The `(not (equal? 3 mult))` condition is making your example return an empty list, think about it: you're saying that `mult` is `3`, but then you check it `mult` is *not* `3`

This should fix the issues:

```
(define (keep-multiples-of-three-or loi mult)
  (cond [(empty? loi) empty]
        [(or (equal? (remainder (first loi) 3) 0)
             (equal? (remainder (first loi) mult) 0))
         (cons (first loi)
               (keep-multiples-of-three-or (rest loi) mult))]
        [else (keep-multiples-of-three-or (rest loi) mult)]))
```

For example:

```
(keep-multiples-of-three-or (list 9 3) 3)
=> '(9 3)
(keep-multiples-of-three-or (list 1 3 5 9) 5)
=> '(3 5 9)
```